Sacrifice condition of Hope of Ghirapur
Can I sacrifice Hope of Ghirapur anytime? For example, a turn it hasn't dealt combat damage.

This question is possibly a duplicate of Can I attempt to activate an equipment's equip ability without a valid target?. We've had similar questions for triggered abilities and spells.

@Rainbolt not an exact duplicate, but in this case the type differences don't matter, you can't do anything that targets without a valid target (unless it uses the magic words "up to")

@Rainbolt it's not an equipment ability

Hope of Ghirapur's abiltity is an activated ability. On this site, duplicate means "This question already has an answer here." not "This question uses the exact same cards, with the exact same card types, and the exact same board state." So I acknowledge that Hope of Ghirapur isn't an equipment card, but you'll have to help me understand how that invalidates the answers on the linked question.

No, as you cannot select a legal target if Hope has not dealt combat damage, so you cannot activate the ability.
(see rulings here: 115.1c An activated ability is targeted if it identifies something it will affect by using the phrase “target [something],” where the “something” is a phrase that describes an object and/or player. The target(s) are chosen as the ability is activated; see rule 602.2b.)
